# What exactly is the "data" field required as arg while instantiating an ink contract?

Tags: ink, pallet-contracts, contracts

The image below shows a decoded finalized transaction that deploys a flipper contract on my local substrate network.
I am not sure what the **data** field represents here.

[image: Contract deployment transaction]

Answer (score 2):

It is the data passed to the constructor of the contract.

[Pallet contracts docs](https://docs.rs/pallet-contracts/latest/pallet_contracts/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.instantiate_with_code)

Comment: To expand, data is an encoded `message` or `constructor` selector (because you can have multiple constructors) with input for it (if needed).

Comment: Well in my case the function signature looks like this:
`pub fn new(init_value: bool) -> Self `
I believe I initialized it with `false`.
Can you elaborate what encoding or other mechanism led it to be `0x9bae9d5e00`?

Comment: first 4 bytes is the selector (`9bae9d5e`) then you have the args (00 = false in your case)

Comment: I need to pass the data field through my code using polkadot-js/api library.
So can you tell me how I can get the first 4 bytes i.e. the selector, given the function signature and the params passed during the contract instantiation?